# Multiplication of a matrix by scalar zero

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, icc

I am working on a c++ project to do some computations. I am using the boost library to do these computations. I had a strange bug (results were not right or the program was freezing). When I checked what was happening, I realized that after creating a matrix of doubles and multiplying the matrix by 0 (to ensure that everything is equal to zero e.g.:

```
matrix<double> *A=new matrix<double>(10,100);
(*A)*=0.0;
```

My matrix was not always filled by strict 0 (this is inside a method that is called a LOT, the pointer is deleted correctly and I checked that I do not have any memory leaks), sometimes negative zeros (-0.0) or even NaNs!!
Then I realized that using the method clear() will set all the values to the default (which is 0 for double). So even if I do have a solution, this is very peculiar! 
As usual, the question is: did I do something wrong (more likely) or is there a bug in the library (less likely)?

PS: I do use the intel compiler (version 2015)

Comment: You are just creating a matrix, you are not initializing its content.
Initialize that first with some values and then do operations on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in [Boost Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm#12Example),

```
matrix (size_type size1, size_type size2): Allocates an uninitialized matrix that holds size1 rows of size2 elements.
```

So you are using a matrix not initialized, causing those strange errors. 
Create first a zero-matrix or an identity matrix:

```
identity_matrix<double> matrix(3); //create a 3x3 identity matrix
zero_matrix<double> matrix(3, 3);  //create a 3x3 zero matrix
```

Comment: The goal of the multiplication was to initialize the matrix through a multiplication by 0. apparently, using the method clear will initialize and set every element to 0. Thanks for the answer...